# How to send email using sendgrid in google cloud endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, sendgrid

I'm trying to send email using Sendgrid with Google Cloud Endpoints. Here is the reference: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/sendgrid

However, after copy `Sendgrid.java` to the src directory of the app, when I try to build the project, the error message says:

> package com.google.appengine.labs.repackaged.org.json does not exist

It seems this package is not available to endpoints, but only app engine.

So, how can I send email from Google Cloud Endpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to write the code for sending the email in the App Engine project and create an endpoint method containing this code. You can then call the endpoint method from a mobile or a Javascript client using Google Cloud Endpoints.

Comment: I don't have app engine project, but only endpoints to create mobile service(api). then how to achieve the goal ?

Comment: Endpoints are just that - endpoints or interfaces to a backend api through URLs or methods. Where is your backend API located if not on App Engine?

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding now.I just added the appengine-api-labs jar, and the code works.

Comment: i want to send email with html body, can anyone tell me how to do that?